# How to use assignment operator on proxy of index operator

Tags: c++, typecast-operator

In the following code I made a template class, Its initialized in main function and I'm trying to assign `char*` as you can see below but It isn't working. I think the issue is in assign operator function I defined in Proxy class but I can't figure it out

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector {
 public:
    T *p;

    Vector(int size) {
        p = new T[size];
    }

    class Proxy {
        Vector &a;
        int i;

     public:
        Proxy(Vector &a, int i) : a(a), i(i) {
        }

        void operator=(const T x) {
            a.p[i] = x;
        }
    };

    Proxy operator[](int i) {
        return Proxy(*this, i);
    }
};

int main() {
    Vector<char *> sv1(2);
    sv1[0] = "John";
    sv1[1] = "Doe";
}
```

I'm getting following error;

[image: Error]

I already tried setting parameter in assignment operator function to `const`, I also tried implicitly typecasting to `T` nothing has worked

Comment: What does "tried setting `const` parameter" mean?

Comment: void operator=(const T x) const {
   a.p[i] = x;
  }

Comment: No, you should make the template parameter a `const char *`.

Comment: No, by explicitly specifying type it'll lose its purpose. I want it to use Type ```T``` from template

Comment: `Vector<const char *> sv1(2);` -- which part of this, that specifies the template parameter as `const char *`, was unclear?

Comment: yes that cleared the error, but can't we change something in template so we wouldn't need to set the type constant while initializing ?

Comment: No. `"literal strings"` are `const char *`s. C++ does not work any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector {
public:
    T* p;
    int sz;

    Vector(int size) {
        p = new T[size];
        sz = size;
    }


    template<class T>
    class Proxy {
        Vector<T>& v;
        int i;
        
    public:
        Proxy(Vector<T>& vec, int index) :v(vec),i(index) { }

        void operator= (const T val) { v.p[i] = val; }
    }; 

    Proxy<T> operator[](int index) { return Proxy<T>(*this, index); }
};
```

Your code will work with any basic type, (`int`, `char`, `double`) and pointers, but not, for example, with this:

```
int main() {
    Vector<char*> sv1(2);
    sv1[0] = "John";
    sv1[1] = "Doe";
}
```

Firstly, the Vector points to a `char*`, not a string literal (`const char*`). You'd have to cast it using a C-style cast or a `const_cast`. Example:

```
int main() {
    Vector<char*> sv1(2);
    sv1[0] = const_cast<char*>("John"); //succeeds
    sv1[1] = (char*)"Doe"; //succeeds

    sv1[0] = "John"; //fails
    sv1[1] = "Doe"; //fails
}
```

A string literal is always a `const char*` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have same error writing code:

> char * whatever = "something";

This code is absolutely wrong at least for string:

```
void operator=(const T x)
{
    a.p[i] = x;
}
```

Step 1: allocate buffer;
Step 2: copy string to allocated buffer.

Your code is OK for primitives like char, int, etc. The following code should work:

```
int main() {
    Vector<char> sv1(2);
    sv1[0] = 'J';
    sv1[1] = 'D';
}
```